# Interpreting interacting random effects in lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, random-effects-model, nested-data

My questions is about how to interpret the output from lme4 for interacting random effects.

Our model is as follows:

```
LMM4 <- lmerTest::lmer(
  ZySafetyFear2.1 ~ condition + sex + (1 | MediatorID:researchID )
    + (1|MediatorID) + (1 | researchID) + (1|JudgeID), 
  data=df_outcomes)
```

Here, we have condition and sex as fixed effects. Each individual is nested in a couple, in a mediator, and in a judge. We know that couples are nested within mediators.

For instance, in the following image, where researchID is grouping for couples, and we want to nest couples within mediators, I understand that the variance presented for research ID is the amount of variance that the grouping by couples accounts for. However, I'm unclear on how to interpret the variance for MediatorID:researchID. Any help would be much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The simplest syntax for your equation would be `ZySafetyFear2.1 ~ condition + sex + (1 | judge/mediator/research)` as long as you have true nesting of person with mediator within judge. If you have unique IDs within the judges, within mediators and within research, you can simply use `ZySafetyFear2.1 ~ condition + sex + (1 | judge) + (1 | mediator) + (1 | research)`.

Comment: I apologize, I did not explain the data fully here. 1/3 of the participants do NOT have mediators. Mainly I would like to know how to interpret the variance for an interaction of random effects. We added unique mediator ID dummy codes for all of those 1/3 couples who don't have mediators. Thus, there is still nesting of couples within mediators (partially), and nesting couples withing judges, but the mediators are not nested within judges. Some mediators may see cases from three different judges for instance. Thus, we incorporate nesting terms because mediators are crossed with judges.

Comment: So use the second specification first. Lme4 does not care about nesting, as long as you have unique IDs. For now, your model specification is incorrect, which is why you have a several 0 variances.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean about Lme4 not caring about nesting? Also, we are getting 0 variances for Judge regardless of the model specification (also tried it with the second specification). We thought this meant that the grouping from judge simply doesn't impact anything - is that the correct interpretation?

Comment: In lme4, it does not matter whether your grouping variables are nested or crossed. As long as every researcher/mediator/judge has a unique ID, it does not affect estimation. Additionally, it is highly unlikely that a random intercept variance is exactly zero unless that effect is already captured by another variable in the model.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. As you noted, the judge variance is getting captured by the mediator and couple random intercept variances.